# Updating One Cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want so that when I touch on a button, it will cause a label to expand.

I tried with `numberOfLines` and it works, but when scrolling the table view, the label and the other cells get also expanded :(

How can I be able to update just one cell?

I use `table.beginUpdates` but it's not the answer, because when scrolling downwards, other cells will also be changed.

This is my code, for example:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(indexPath: indexPath) as     FoodTableViewCell
        cell.title.text = "adshflakdsjfhalkdsjfhladksjfhadlkfhadlkfhaldkfhdlkfhadjfhaldfhaldfhaldskfhdslkhflakdshfladksfhladfhladfhal"
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: CellDelegate {

   func action(cell: FoodTableViewCell) {
       cell.title.numberOfLines = 0
   }
}
```

I want this:

[image]

Comment: Is the button which you want to touch is inside the cell? or somewhere else?

Comment: It is happening because you are reusing the cell.

Comment: yes. that's right @Jeet

Comment: @NiravD no . it's happen when I scroll down and i see other cell is changed

Comment: @FarhadFaramarzi That was i'm saying it is happening because you are reusing the cell in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

Comment: @NiravD yes. it's right

Comment: You need to create a model or `NSArray` to keep track of which cell had the button clicked. And in your `cellForRow` check if the cell has been clicked and set the number of lines appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I solve . I set a flag in model and check with it